# How to select standalone-tag (like input) by using DOM-tree?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to select an Input-field to add placeholder by javascript, but it seems not to work... this is my code:

```js
function scriptparent() {
var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    scriptTag = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1];
    var parent = scriptTag.parentNode;
    return parent;
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <script>scriptparent().firstChild.setAttribute("placeholder","something");</script>
</div>
```

I also tried different variants of this (like to get previousSibling of script), but didn't get it to work. 
This snippet works well on other Elements, if you wonder why i try to do this is because the "something" is a language addicted variable from json-file, it's like

"scriptparent().firstChild.setAttribute("placeholder",lang.nav.search.placeholder[language]);"

in real.

I'm a bit of a javascript noob, so it would be nice if someone could point me to the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`. Otherwise you're getting the text node representing the white-space before the `input`.

Also, make sure `scriptparent()` is global. I don't know where SO's code snippets put the JS, but your function wasn't global or defined in time, so I just moved the script to the HTML.

```html
<script>
  function scriptparent() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    return scripts[scripts.length - 1].parentNode;
  };
</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <script>scriptparent().firstElementChild.placeholder = "something";</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that works :) Any explanation why i have to use firstElementChild instead of firstChild?

Comment: @Lukas: It's because the `.firstChild` is a text node representing the white-space before the `input`.

Comment: WOW thats crazy... so if i remove whitespace firstChild works. Didn't even know about this behavior.

Comment: Yep, basically everything in your HTML gets represented as a DOM node. Old IE left out white-space, but the W3 spec requires that it's represented.